# Xcode AppDelegate wont link to textfields

Tags: appdelegate

I am following along in a book to learn swift and I am building a basic loan calculator for OS-X using XCode.  I am getting two errors in my code and it wont allow me to attach the Outlets to my textfields.  The errors are:

1. Line 16 - Use of Undeclared type "NSTestField" but I changed it to NSTextField and it still shows an error under the mistyped var name.
2. Line 35 - Postfix "." is reserved.  The error carrot is on the dot between loanAmountField and doubleValue.

Also, it wont allow me to drag the outlets into my app.  I am guessing I did not attach the appdelegate file to the right window since the window option is not marked but I cant figure out how to do that.  The book just says it should already be marked.

[My code showing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/852Hx.png)
(Sorry, I tried using the "code sample" button when posting this but even after indenting 4 spaces and pasting my code it continued to tell me I did not indent.)

[The appdelegate showing that "window" isnt marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1zwm.png)

Comment: For code, don't try to indent 4 spaces then paste - paste it all, then highlight it all, and click the `{}` button last.  You can [edit] your question to make those changes pretty easily.

Comment: Tried it.  Pasted it, gave every line 4 spaces and then highlighted it and hit the code block button and got a big mess

Comment: The code block button is there to give you those spaces, as I said, you *don't* have to put them in yourself if you use the button. One thing to check is that there is an empty line before the code block, don't put it right after a sentence.  Then, whether by hand or by button, you'll get your code block.

Comment: Back on a computer, so .... if you still can't make it work, if you just post the big mess and explain your difficulties, someone will probably come along and edit it up nicely for you.

Comment: It seems to have been my fault.  I did not setup the project correctly.  I went back through the project and this time everything worked great and looked just like it did in the book.